# redmine ckeditor plugin uploadimage

Tags: ckeditor, redmine

i use redmine ckeditor plugin... I'd like to attach an image by drag and drop.

i downloaded 'uploadimage' plugin and paste '/plugin' folder

path is...

C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.1-0\apps\redmine\htdocs\plugins\redmine_ckeditor\assets\ckeditor\plugins\uploadimage

and **config.js...**

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */


CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {


    config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
    config.uploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';   

    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';   
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';   
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';   
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images';   
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

};
```

but, i restart redmine, **the plug-in will not apply.**

my redmine version is (bitnami)3.1.2

ckeditor version is lastest version (4.6.2)

1) What are the other plug-ins that attach images by drag and drop?

2) Is the plug-in installation correct?

Comment: Oh! i solved problem....
C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.1-0\apps\redmine\htdocs\plugins\redmine_ckeditor\assets\ckeditor-contrib\plugins

Comment: You are uploading files via connector.php ?